# How to use reduce to replace filter and map in typescript

Tags: typescript, reduce

I have a simple example like

```
    interface employer {
      name: string;
      age: number;
    }

    const arr: employer[] = [{name:'Amy',age:18},{name:'Bob',age:20}];

    let data = arr.reduce((c, b) =>  b.age > 18 ? [...c, b] : c,[])

    console.log(data)
```

I just want to filer `arr` array and return the age of the person is higher than 18 for example
But I get errors

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(callbackfn: (previousValue: employer, currentValue: employer, currentIndex: number, array: employer[]) => employer, initialValue: employer): employer', gave the following error.
    Type 'employer[]' is missing the following properties from type 'employer': name, age
  Overload 2 of 3, '(callbackfn: (previousValue: never[], currentValue: employer, currentIndex: number, array: employer[]) => never[], initialValue: never[]): never[]', gave the following error.
    Type 'employer[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
      Type 'employer' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

For this `b.age > 18 ? [...c, b] : c`
I think it worked for javascript
How can we fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I try another way

```
interface employer {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const arr: employer[] = [{name:'Amy',age:18},{name:'Bob',age:20}];

let data: employer[] = arr.reduce((c: employer[], b: employer) =>  b.age > 18 ? [...c, b] : c,[])

console.log(data)
```

Comment: You are losing type safety with this though

Comment: Why do you think it is incorrect @GeorgiosKampitakis?

Comment: Using the any defeats the purpose of using types, if you do 
`arr.reduce((c:any, b:any) =>  b.wrong > 18 ? [...c, b] : c,[])` this will stil compile but throw runtime error as `b.wrong` exists in any type.

Answer (score 3):

In order to fix this error, you need to add type on the `reduce` function. You can do this by calling

```
let data = arr.reduce<employer[]>((c, b) =>  b.age > 18 ? [...c, b] : c,[])
```

also, this is valid

```
let data = arr.reduce((c, b) =>  b.age > 18 ? [...c, b] : c,[] as employer[])
```

but I think the first one looks better.

You can find a working example in this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAggWwA4BsD2BPaZAbwChlzkQ40IAuZAZzClAHMBuMiuVuygVzQAjaJwC%20JEghwgmyOFCj102fNADaAXWQBeZOqJUatAOQBBNHhMAaHnQCMADjHXD1OiYBCOITbu0AJgAGMU1OEiwIMGQAEzgwOF15RQA6KAgY-iQAHhVcAigtAD4AChKEa2QhAEpdIvIhFLtkeqdkAH59FO6Kqu16Cq1qyWlZHEiU3FYSuIThoA)